# Jquery Autocomplete - Textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI autocomplete but i wish to append the search function to a textbox value.

```
   $( "#Textbox" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

The above is a example snippet.

I wish for the end user to scroll using up and down on the keyboard to select a single figure. For example, If the user was to enter "a" it will bring the first result in which they can use up or down to bring up the value.

It could come down to me using a single textbox.

Comment: This looks correct based on what you have described. What exactly is not working? Can you make a working example with jsfiddle?